# Constructive Criticism on answers and comments

Tags: discussion

I expect this to get heavily downvoted but I have observed something I am not happy with the SO community and I'd like to share my thoughts.

A lot of the time people, with good will, end up being very pedantic when commenting or answering to the point of being detrimental to the question or obscuring the meaning of something for no good reason.

One example of this is, a long time ago, I wrote a question where I asserted that in C a `char*` and a `char[]` are the same thing. I stated that arrays and pointers are the same.

Multiple people corrected me, indicating that when declaring an array with a given length like `char temp[100]`, the compiler knows the size of the structure and does some extra checks and so on...

They were not wrong, but that was beyond the point, the point of saying that they are the same, is that they are both addresses pointing to a continuous region in memory that can be accessed through indexing (and for all given purposes if char* is a pointer to a single value, it's the same as an array of one element).

These people were not rude, they were not trying to be obnoxious, but it remained that the discussion was derailed to try to explain how char* and char[] are or not the same thing rather than focus on the actual questio/answer.

This is just one example, but another one would be, I see a lot a pattern when someone asks "How to do X", and then most of the answers are "You should not do X, do Y instead, it's better".

And off course these people are well intentioned when answering that, but a lot of the time that's just not helpful. In my case for example, I do a lot of "experimental" developping, where I am trying to find edge cases and dirty hacks in libraries and so on, just for fun. Sometimes I am well aware that what I am asking SHOULD not be done, but I want to know if I CAN.

And something that is particularily bad is, when new users start asking questions, I usually see the people answering with full blown terminology and details to a question asked by someone that is clearly just a novice and won;t get half of it (Likely they do this in an efforth to create a good quality answer that will get upvotes, but the consequence is that the poster of the question won't be able to benefit from the answer).

Sometimes is the opposite, people provide a minimum answer that technically contains enough information but it's obvious that whoever is asking won;t understand from that alone.

Overall these are things that contribute to making SO a somewhat toxic place to ask questions, specially for new users. I believe we as a community could make an efforth to be slightly kinder. I know the point of the website is to be a place of high quality questions and answers, but a lot of the time it's hard to detemrine what that means, specially for new users.

I am not trying to trash on the good will of people, specially those than answer questions, I just want to put this as a reminder that sometimes kindness in an answer may make it clearer than pedantic expertise.

Comment: But the site already has recourse for outright rudeness - flag the offenders. If the offense is mild, the comment will go away, if more severe, the offender will be punished. The rules state that we should be nice to one another, and it is up to all of us to police this policy. That being said, there are other issues at play here, but these have already been so well discussed in previous similar posts on meta, that I have to ask -- how is yours different? What does this post bring that's new to the table?

Comment: Please see [Consequences for rude comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291391/consequences-for-rude-comment). Also please read [this **very** relevant blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: Guys read the post, I am not complaining about people being rude, I am talking about them being unintentionally pedantic

Comment: And "And something that is particularily bad is, when new users start asking questions, I usually see the people answering with full blown terminology and details to a question asked by someone that is clearly just a novice and won;t get half of it (Likely they do this in an efforth to create a good quality answer that will get upvotes, but the consequence is that the poster of the question won't be able to benefit from the answer)." -- I'd rather see this than code-dump answers. Ask yourself, what is the prime purpose of this site? It's not to give an answer just for the question asker.

Comment: You may be missing the entire point of this site. Again, it's not to help out newbies by giving simplistic answers but rather to provide a library of common questions and answers, Q/A's that are helpful to future visitors. Most of the time users of this site shouldn't even be asking questions but rather searching the site, since that's where its benefit shines through. And pedantic is not a bad thing since many comments are made to try to make the question more specific, more accurate and more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Take into account that SO itself released a public statement appologizing that, in their quest for having a sit with good answers, they have promoted a toxic environment that is specially hostile to newcomers. I know what the purpose of the site is, It does not change the fact that new people feel very unwelcommed when they first try to interact with SO

Comment: I have given you a link to that very same blog post.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels SO is meant to be a repository of HIGH QUALITY questions and answers. I know this, I know it's not a discussion forum. I know it's not a tutorial site, I know it's not meant to be a help newbies site. That does not mean that answers cannot be formatted according to the asker and still be relevant. If it's a simple but good answer to a question that has not been asked before, it will be useful for both the asker and future askers with the same level of knowledge. If answers are always too technical then they are only useful for people with high technical knowledge

Comment: If you don't like an answer, if you think it's not appropriate, then down-vote it, and then if you desire, supply your own more appropriate answer. Again, we already have mechanisms in place to allow you to express your opinion on this. What *concrete* changes are you proposing?

Comment: My post is in an of itself part of the change I am suggesting, I just want people to be more aware of how they answer and try to take into consideration that sometimes you can ommit techincal details and make an answer clearer for an audience with less experience (that is still a high quality question, just one targeted at a difference audience) and be more concsious of how what they do may contribute to a more toxic community.

For example read back our interactions in this post, it seems to me that you have just assumed my argument for me and passed judgment [...]

Comment: [...] without trying to understand my argument. And we are now having a conversation about it. I made the post long to try to explain myself in detail precisely to avoid confusion as to what I was saying, yet it would seem to me (and I say it with no ill intention) that you jumped to conlusions before attempting to understand what I meant. An this is exactly part of the problem I am trying to describe in my post.

Comment: so let me summarize what you want : You are fine about what the site offer and you want to change people behavior? ...something we cannot do unfortunately

Comment: @Makogan: "*It does not change the fact that new people feel very unwelcommed when they first try to interact with SO*" What evidence do you have that the things you describe here are the reasons why? Equally importantly, even if they are, we cannot let misinformation stand. Pointers aren't arrays in C, and if a question says that they are, *someone* will read it and believe it. That's far worse than being a "toxic environment"; that's being a *misinformation* environment. That should be countered, shouldn't it?

Comment: The difference between the arrays and the pointers exists only at the compiler level. And only on the scope of the declaration of the array, when you pass them across functions there is barely any difference. It's not missinformation, arrays in C ARE pointers, or rather, a pointer is the same as an array with just one element, that is a perfectly valid statement or at least I honestly think of them that way because that's how I use them. An array is nothing but a pointer to a contigous region of memory holding associated data. A pointer is the same but that region is just one element.

Comment: A pointer is NOT the same as an array with one element, and misunderstandings of that point are at the root of many C questions.  Compilers ARE pedantic, and the sooner that student programmers learn that, the better off they will be.

Comment: @Makogan: "*I honestly think of them that way because that's how I use them*" That is a limited and limiting thought. If you truly want to "find edge cases and dirty hacks in libraries", you cannot do that by choosing to believe whatever you want to believe. You have to understand how these systems *actually work*, not merely use them within the little box you set up for yourself.

Comment: It is because I have had to use them that I think of them that way. First, I had to build an embedded program for the raspberry pi 3, this required working at the lowest level of programming, combining assembly and C, and there is no difference in the way these two structures get compiled. But moreover, the compiler can only differentiate them as long as they remain on the same scope, as soon as you pass an array down to the next function, the difference between the array and the pointer is lost. You need to remember the abstraction yourself from that point onwards.

Comment: And thinking of them in this way has been useful, for example I interfaced a wavefront loader from a friends library to a project I worked on by abusing the fact that I knew the structures in an array were compiled contiguously and typecasted it to an array of floats, and the program worked exactly as expected when I did that. Because what the compiler thinks something is at any given point is just an abstraction, one you can ignore if you know how to trick it, and this can be useful. An array and a pointer are the same, you could access the data of any pointer by doing ptr[0] instead of *ptr.

Comment: @Makogan well, yes,  they are the same.  Well, mod them being different sizes,  and that arrays have actual storage space for data where pointers do not.

Comment: There is a difference between saying "for all intents and purposes here it is the same. Don't  make the mistake of thinking they are identical! Actually, the difference (even if not fully relevant here) is ....." and just saying something wrong. I don't understand what you expected ....you wanted the users to agree with what you say, knowing  it's  not exact? You do know we are building a high quality knowledge repository?

Comment: @Patrice It's nto wrong, it's 100% correct. Do the following experiment, wherever you have a pointer, instead of erefrencing like *ptr do ptr[], and whenver you would declare a pointer, don't declare it as int *ptr declare it as int ptr[1]. You will notice that the behaviour of your program is identical. You have not allocated mor or less memory nor have you had any impact on performance. They are the same, not they can be considered the same, even the compiler allows you to swapp between the twop as you wish. A pointer is just an array with one element

Comment: @Makogan It's not correct, it's 100% wrong. Do the following experiment, wherever you have an int array, declare it instead as ' int *ptr'.  I wonder what will happen now...

Comment: @MartinJames

    int hello[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int* hello2 = hello;

This compiles

Comment: **Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.** Period.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-char-pointer-and-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c).

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22075346/918959).

Comment: One could say that you truly master C when you fully understand that an array is not a pointer ;) There is hundred of newbies that continue to smash that a pointer is an array, you just appear to be one of them.

Comment: @Makogan it's also not what Martin said to do...try int* hello instead of int hello[] in your example. It won't compile, no?

Answer (score 15):

Let me try to see if I fully understand your issues:

1. That we as a group are being too pedantic, that we're focusing on the small at the expense of the big.
2. That some answers to newbies, while perhaps being correct are not "newbie-appropriate", in that they present their discussion in an advanced way
3. That answers or comments that call out [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type questions are wrong, that it is better to give the answer the question that the poster asks rather than explain to them that their total approach is wrong

As to these points, please allow points of my own:

- Regarding pedantry (corrected): Most of these issues usually concern comments to questions (or answer), making corrections or asking for clarification. Possible solutions include addressing them, and perhaps using them to improve the question. Most are made in a spirit to improve and clarify, and if taken in this light, they can be helpful and increase the chances of the actual question being answered. I cannot imagine how these comments could prevent a question from being answered. Yes the commenter might not answer it, but he/she's only one out of thousands. The other option is to simply ignore them if you the questioner don't feel that they are relevant.
- Regarding overly technical answers: If you see this, and you feel that it hampers answer quality, then again we have recourses available including posting a comment to the answerer asking for simplification and clarification of specific points, as well as up-voting and down-voting the various answers based on *your* perception of their quality, as well as providing your own answer that you feel is more appropriate to the current level of the questioner.
- Regarding "Y" answers to XY Problem type questions: You have the same recourses as listed above. Myself, I am a strong believer in giving "Y" answers to the "X" questions if I know they exist.

The question I have for you is what *specific* recommendations do you have for change in SO policy and procedure for making it better with regards to the point you're making. We can all talk "being nicer and more newbie friendly" til we're blue in the face, but real change (if it is in fact needed) would require some structural change that rewards good behavior and penalizes perceived bad behavior. Do you have a concrete recommendation to changing the site's reward/penalty system that would improve it?

Comment: Pedantic note, the term is pedantry not pedantism :P

Comment: @Makogan: well played and touché.  :)

Comment: Well if you want an actual proposal for this, one I talked a long time ago and got criticized for suggesting, I'd like to be able to add anonymous feedback to questions (to prevent witch hunts) which could themselves have votes with less point rewards. Another thing is, maybe have an option when upvoting to mark an answer as "kind" or "nice" and this would get maybe like 1 or two points as bonification for the asker?

For the XY problem, it's more complicated, because what I was describing was not XY per se, it was asking Y and people answering X when I do want to know Y, even if X is better

Comment: @Makogan The problem here? There are too many users who don't know that they have an XY problem, and answering the X part helps them. If you're **absolutely** sure that you **need** the Y part in **your** question then you can make a remark in the comment (I know that I should not do ..., but I want the answer to ... because ...).

Comment: @Makogan We don't have "nice" or 'not nice", only "correct" or "incorrect". Because we (should) vote on contents, not users.

Comment: @user202729 interactions with others here involve much more than voting on content quality and also include commenting, asking and answering, and in these interactions there is (and should be) a "be nice" policy.

Comment: We're not a tutorial service.